# Parent with Childs MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, hierarchical-data, recursive-query

My SQL-Query looks like this:

```
WITH RECURSIVE a (templid,type,parentid,enname,dename,sys,level) AS 
(
 SELECT templid,type,parentid,enname,dename,sys,1 
 FROM template 
 WHERE type = :type AND parentid = :parentId 
 UNION ALL 
 SELECT b.templid,b.type,b.parentid,b.enname,b.dename,b.sys,(level+1) as level 
 FROM template b JOIN a ON b.parentid = a.templid
) SELECT * FROM a
```

what gives me the result:

[image: MySQL-Result]

The result is ordered by level but what I need is the result ordered by parentid:

[image: MySQL-Result wanted]

Answer (score 1):

You can keep track of the path to each node, and use that for ordering:

```
with recursive a (templid, type, parentid, enname, dename, sys, level, path) as (
    select templid, type, parentid, enname, dename, sys, 1, templid as path
    from template 
    where type = :type and parentid = :parentid 
    union all 
    select b.templid, b.type, b.parentid, b.enname, b.dename, b.sys, a.level + 1, concat(a.path, '/', b.templid)
    from template b 
    inner join a on b.parentid = a.templid
) 
select * from a order by path
```